# ParseExact and CurrentCulture?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

*I always see this sample of code but never know exactly when to use which :*

suppose I have a date to parse : `13 December 2011`

It can be done with

```
 var g=DateTime.ParseExact("13 December 2011","d MMMM yyyy",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None );
```

or by

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); 
 var g=DateTime.ParseExact("13 December 2011","d MMMM yyyy",null,DateTimeStyles.None );
```

Both supply the same result.

When should I use which ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example will use that culture for that sepcific operation.

The second example will change the culture of the running thread, affecting that operation **and subsequent operations that are affected by the current culture**  until the thread culture changes.

So use the one that's appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

The result for that parsing is the same, but if you set the current culture of the thread, that will also affect any other culture dependant operations that you do later on.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the first. As for the second, you have changed the current culture of your application in current thread will might be lead to error, if you are using different culture with `US`.

Answer (score 1):

First line will use the culture that is specified in a ParseExact method as the second argument. This will parse date in en-US culture even if the culture of the thread is different. The second will change the culture of the thread and the call for ParseExact will use that new culture that has been set in the previous line.